# Accurately measure elapsed wall clock time in .NET

Tags: .net, performance

What is the most convenient way of accurately measuring elapsed wall clock time in .NET?  I'm looking for something with microsecond accuracy if possible (10^-6 seconds).

Comment: Is elapsed "wall clock time" equivalent to elapsed time?

Comment: @spender: [Wall clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) is the total time needed to complete a task.

Comment: Ah. OK, as opposed to CPU time. Got it now.

Comment: It comes from the notion of measuring the elapsed time using a clock hanging on the wall.  It is totally oblivious to CPU time or anything else going on inside the machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is your best bet. However, the exact accuracy will depend on the hardware on the computer you're using, i.e. whether a high-resolution performance counter is available. (You can check that with the [`IsHighResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) field.)

Sample use:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// Do stuff here
sw.Stop();
TimeSpan time = sw.Elapsed;
```

Note that if you use the [`ElapsedTicks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedticks.aspx) property, that's measured in *timer* ticks which is not the same as the ticks used in `DateTime` and `TimeSpan`. That's caught me out before now - which is why I always use [`ElapsedMilliseconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsedmilliseconds.aspx) or the [`Elapsed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed.aspx) property.

Comment: This looks perfect.  On my system the `Frequency` field claims a resolution of better than one tenth of a microsecond.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Stopwatch Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) and [Stopwatch.Frequency Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class which provides waiting on this scale since I assume in the end that is what you need to do. The StopWatch @ CPU time will possibly get a APC and you will miss your end time.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725711/obtaining-microsecond-precision-using-net-without-platform-invoke

For a better way IMHO

Let me know if you find otherwise!